# Do we need absolute continuity of $f$ for $\left|\int_1^2 f'(x) \log x\, dx \right| \le \int_1^2 |f(x)|\, dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-continuity

> **Problem.** Assume that $f:[1,2]\to \Bbb R$ is absolutely continuous, with $f(2) = 0$. Prove that $$\left|\int_1^2 f'(x) \log x\, dx \right| \le \int_1^2 |f(x)|\, dx \tag{1}$$
> *Source:* [Problem $2$, Pg. $2$.](https://www.colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/absolutelycontinuous.pdf)

The proof is quite straightforward; we use integration by parts to get $$\int_1^2 f'(x) \log x\, dx = f(2)\log 2 - f(1)\log 1 - \int_1^2 \frac{f(x)}{x}\, dx = -\int_1^2 \frac{f(x)}{x}\, dx$$
so that $$\left|\int_1^2 f'(x) \log x\, dx  \right| = \left|\int_1^2 \frac{f(x)}{x}\, dx \right|\le \int_1^2 \left|\frac{f(x)}{x} \right|\, dx \le \int_1^2 |f(x)|\, dx$$
as required.

**My Question:** Do we really need absolute continuity of $f$ to get $(1)$? What if $f$ is just (i) differentiable almost everywhere on $[1,2]$? or (ii) of bounded variation? Essentially, I would like to know if a weaker hypothesis on $f$ could also lead to $(1)$.

Note that functions of bounded variation can be decomposed as a sum of two monotone functions, and hence, are differentiable almost everywhere. We interpret $\int f'(x)\log x\, dx$ in the sense of the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Differentiable almost everywhere on $[1,2]$". No, using Cantor function you can construct $f$ such that $f'=1$ almost everywhere and that $f(2)=0$, yet $\| f\|_{\infty}$ is close to $0$ however you want.
2. "Of continuous bounded variation".  <s>Yes, but you have to specify what you mean by the integrand with $f'(x)$.</s> . **As OP has changed his question, the answer for this case is now NO.** Counterexamples are as above.
3. 4. "Uniformly continuous" and "continuous". Generally no, the problem again is how you define the integrand.

Comment: For $(2)$; functions of bounded variation are differentiable a.e., so we can integrate $f'(x)\log x$ w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$. Right?

Comment: @heroic-harmonic: I would again say no. If you look back at Case1, the constructed functions are always of bounded variations. The correct modification should be to replace "$f'(x)\mathrm{d}x$" by $\mu(\mathrm{d}x)$ where $\mu$ is a signed measure such that $f(x)= \mu(x,2]$.